# how to calculate unknown probabilities in the bayesian network

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayesian-networks

I am working on a bayesian network problem. I read the following network from [this website](https://controls.engin.umich.edu/wiki/index.php/Bayesian_network_theory) (see the worked out example 1):

[image]

Note also a property of the alarm: "The alarm goes off if the reactor temperature is too high or the pressure in a storage tank is too high."

The authors infer two other probabilities that are not in the tables:

1. "as soon as the cold water becomes low, you have at least a 94% chance of a high temperature alarm, regardless of whether or not a side reaction occurs".

How are they able to infer that?

2. "Conversely, the presence of a side reaction here only creates a 90% chance of alarm trigger".

Again, how can they infer that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is NOT about programming.

Comment: @YuHao I am new to stackOverflow. can you please tell me , where can I post this kind of thing ?

Comment: I really don't know, just seems not about specific programming problem.

Comment: This should be migrated to Cross Validated, but I suggest you clarify the question before flagging for migration. There is not enough information in the probability tables to infer the probability of the Alarm. Could you add a link to the website you found it on, and add any other information that looks useful? e.g. Is the Alarm variable an OR-function of its parents?

Comment: @LizzieSilver editing done.